# Android IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to add RowItem to ListView

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I'm trying to extract some data from a JSON object to insert into a CustomRowItem which is added to a ListView, the JSON is extracted fine but when I try to add the data to the row item I get I: `D/ERROR: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` error.

The full code is below:

```
    protected void parseJsonToCurrencyRowItem(Currency cryptoCurrency) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < returnedJsonArrayResult.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jOb = returnedJsonArrayResult.getJSONObject(i);
            cryptoCurrency.jsonCurrencyName.add(jOb.getString("name"));
            cryptoCurrency.jsonCurrencyName.add(jOb.getString("percent_change_24h"));
            cryptoCurrency.jsonCurrencyName.add(jOb.getString("price_gbp"));
            cryptoCurrency.jsonCurrencyName.add(jOb.getString("24h_volume_gbp"));
            drawListRows(cryptoCurrency, i);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
    }

}

protected void drawListRows(Currency currency, int i) {
    CurrencyRowItem item = new CurrencyRowItem(currency.jsonCurrencyName.get(i), currency.jsonCurrencyPrice.get(i), currency.jsonPercentchange24hr.get(i), currency.jsonVolume24hr.get(i));
    rowItemList.add(item);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The code fails on the `CurrencyRowItem item = new CurrencyRowItem(currency.jsonCurrencyName.get(i), currency.jsonCurrencyPrice.get(i), currency.jsonPercentchange24hr.get(i), currency.jsonVolume24hr.get(i));`

Line and its doing my head in trying to figure it out, thanks for help in advance.

**AdapterCode**

```
public class BrowseCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<CurrencyRowItem> listingRowItems;
    Context context;

    BrowseCustomAdapter(Context context, List<CurrencyRowItem> listingRowItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listingRowItems = listingRowItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listingRowItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listingRowItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return listingRowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView currency_name;
        TextView currency_price;
        TextView curency_percent24hr;
        TextView currency_24hrvolume;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.currency_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.currency_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.crypto_name);
            holder.curency_percent24hr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.crypto_percentage_change);
            holder.currency_price= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.crypto_current_price);
            holder.currency_24hrvolume= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.crypto_volume);

            CurrencyRowItem row_pos = listingRowItems.get(position);

            holder.currency_name.setText(row_pos.currencyName);
            holder.curency_percent24hr.setText(row_pos.currencyPercentageChange);
            holder.currency_price.setText(row_pos.currencyPrice);
            holder.currency_24hrvolume.setText(row_pos.currency24hrVolume);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your adapter code

Comment: Snippet added above

Comment: Always post full stacktrace / LogCat. Also, you should try to break that line into smaller lines such as `itemCurrencyName = currency.jsonCurrencyName.get(i);`, etc. This way you'd exactly know where the problem is occurring.

Comment: How do you know that the variable `i` passed to `drawListRows()` is in the bounds of the array `currency.jsonCurrencyName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be look like:

```
cryptoCurrency.jsonCurrencyName.add(jOb.getString("name"));
        cryptoCurrency.jsonCurrencyPercent.add(jOb.getString("percent_change_24h"));
        cryptoCurrency.jsonCurrencyPrice.add(jOb.getString("price_gbp"));
        cryptoCurrency.jsonCurrencyVolume.add(jOb.getString("24h_volume_gbp"));
```

You not fill data sa this arrays could be empty

Comment: Yup that fixed it! such a stupid oversight ... I really should take regular breaks after staring at this for hours .... thanks alot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your array is empty.

```
D/ERROR: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Try adding this:

```
if (returnedJsonArrayResult != null && 
    !returnedJsonArrayResult.isEmpty()) {
    for (int i = 0; ...) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Also, start your loop integer at 0, not 1.  Arrays are 0 based.  If you start at one you'll always skip the first entry.

Comment: Changed that while trying to debug it, the `.isEmpty()` seems to be unresolved on the array.  When stepping through the loop the data does appear to seem there.

Comment: If you are getting an index out of bounds exception at 0, then your array is empty.